# MultipleSelectionDialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have my multiple selection dialog running and popping up with the right values. However I'm struggling to understand how to set and retrieve the values when the save button is clicked.

My code is the following:

```
   public void addCondition(View view){

        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
        Cursor f = db.rawQuery("select * from assetobservationtypes", null);  
        Log.e("Asset Helper Types:", "Cursor run");
         List<CharSequence> mHelperNames = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
         final ArrayList<String> mHelperNamesID= new ArrayList<String>();  

        if(f.getCount() > 0) {
            f.moveToFirst();
               while(!f.isAfterLast()) {
                   mHelperNames.add(f.getString(f.getColumnIndex("Observation")));
                   mHelperNamesID.add(f.getString(f.getColumnIndex("AssetObsID")));

                    f.moveToNext();
               }
        }

        f.close();

        final List<Integer> mSelectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("My Title")
                    .setMultiChoiceItems(mHelperNames.toArray(new CharSequence[mHelperNames.size()]), null,
                            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which, boolean isChecked) {
                                    if (isChecked) {

                                        mSelectedItems.add(which);
                                    } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {

                                        mSelectedItems.remove(Integer
                                                .valueOf(which));
                                    }
                                }
                            })

                   .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                      
                           txtCondition.setText("set");
                           txtCondition.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4c9226"));
                           count++;
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                   });
            builder.show();
    }
```

I understand the list is in the array mSelectedItems, however when i tried to do a log of mSelectedItems.get(0) on the onclick of setPositiveButton to test it held anything the app just crashed.

How do I retrieve / store these values? And then pre-populate the list next time

Tom

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: That code should work with no problems. The exception you get is an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Hey - The code posted works, but I'm trying to get the values of the selected items on the click

Comment: Well, in the `onClick` method for the `SAVE` button you would have the selected items from the `mSelectedItems` list. If you select a few items in the list and then you press the save button(with the line `Log.e("LOOK_TAG", "Selected items are " + mSelectedItems);` in the save's `onClick` method)doesn't show any results?

Comment: Oh sorry - yeah that does work! How do I set it so it uses that mSelectedItems on load to re-set the selected items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that by pre populating the list next time you want to show the checked items in the `AlertDialog` when the dialog is showed again. In this case make the `mSelectedItems` a field in your `Activity`(will initially be an empty list):

```
final List<Integer> mSelectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and your calling method:

```
public void addCondition(View view) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
    Cursor f = db.rawQuery("select * from assetobservationtypes", null);  
    Log.e("Asset Helper Types:", "Cursor run");
    List<CharSequence> mHelperNames = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    final ArrayList<String> mHelperNamesID= new ArrayList<String>();  
    while(f.moveToNext()) {
        mHelperNames.add(f.getString(f.getColumnIndex("Observation")));
        mHelperNamesID.add(f.getString(f.getColumnIndex("AssetObsID")));
    }
    f.close();
    boolean[] checkedItems = new boolean[mHelperNames.size()];
    for (int  i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
        checkedItems[i] = false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelectedItems.size(); i++) {
        checkedItems[mSelectedItems.get(i).intValue()] = true;
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("My Title").setMultiChoiceItems(mHelperNames.toArray(new CharSequence[mHelperNames.size()]), checkedItems,
                        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which, boolean isChecked) {
                                if (isChecked) {

                                    mSelectedItems.add(which);
                                } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {

                                    mSelectedItems.remove(Integer
                                            .valueOf(which));
                                }
                            }
                        })

               .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                      
                       txtCondition.setText("set");
                       txtCondition.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4c9226"));
                       count++;
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });
        builder.show();
}
```

Keep in mind that the `mHelperNames` list should be the same(you can't change values in the `Cursor`)otherwise you risk in having some inconsistency between checked/unchecked items or even exceptions. I hope the code is right, I didn't tested it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far, it really is appreciated. Most of it works, however I'm getting some strange results! I've uploaded a video of what's happening: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuQUe0uFkFs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @TomBeech I've edited my answer, the first version was faulty the logic I used was incorrect. See if it works now.